# Saving DataSet information between Forms

Tags: c#, dataset

Using C# .Net 4.5.2 in VS2013.

I added a DataSet to my project. I am able to create instances of the DataSet, and add information, however, when I close the form where I did this, the DataSet empties out. Is there a way to work with the main DataSet instead of instances, or is there a way to keep the information in tact between instances?

As a note, I am not using a DataBase. The intent is for when the program closes, the information in the DataSet is dumped to an XML file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want to use only one DataSet for all (lets call it) 'child' forms?
You can build a static class containing your main DataSet to work with over all forms.

Cheers,
Martin